# Is Long Polling only used with SPA?

Tags: jquery, performance, websocket, single-page-application, long-polling

I want to create a notification system such as the one here at SO. I read about **Websockets** and **Long Polling**. My current Website has some AJAX features already but follows the http request pattern, so each site is a new http request.

When using a **Single Page Application** every user would start a long polling request which would run on the server. My concern is that if I start long polling on a certain page and the user changes the site (makes a new http request) polling starts again and I will end up with several running processes on the server per user, since the process from the last page won't stop running. This would be lots of wasted resources.

I am using PHP server side and have the feeling I will run into performance issues real quick when I do it like this. Am I correct? Do I have to choose another approach or build a SPA to create such a feature?

Comment: To avoid an abandoned long-poll, you could have the client run a quick ajax request before leaving the page. The quick request tells the server which long-poll requests are outstanding, and the server then works to cancel them.